# Migration on two schemas

Tags: postgresql, migration, knex.js

I have 2 schemas on my db:`schema1` and `public` and I want to create some tables there. I tried code like this in my migration:

```
return knex.schema

    .raw('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema1;')

    .createTableIfNotExists('table1', table => {
      table.increments('id')
    })

    .withSchema('public')

    .createTableIfNotExists('table2', table => {
      table.increments('id')
    })
```

And I hoped to have: `schema1.table1` and `public.table2` but I don't. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: The create schema statement does exactly that. It does not put it in the path. Either expand the create for  "table1" to include it ".createTableIfNotExists('application.table1'... " or use ".withSchema(application'" before the create table.  Disclaimer: I don't know Knex so not sure of systax needed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Belayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7623856/belayer) is quite correct in the comments, but I'll expand into an answer to demonstrate the syntax. You'll also need to avoid doing things like:

```
createTableIfNotExists('schema1.table1', table => {
```

per [*Identifier Syntax*](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-identifier-syntax), this won't work: just get into the habit of always using `withSchema`.

Further, I don't recommend issuing subsequent `createTable`s without waiting for the previous one to finish. While it *might* work, I think you'll run into trouble with relations etc. That makes your original code more like:

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex
    .raw("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema1")
    .then(() =>
      knex.withSchema("schema1").createTableIfNotExists("table1", table => {
        table.increments("id");
      })
    )
    .then(() =>
      knex.withSchema("public").createTableIfNotExists("table2", table => {
        table.increments("id");
      })
    );
```